# Explain a pig joke. What is funny here?

Tags: meaning, jokes

The joke is: "Yesterday a pig invited me to see his new home. Actually it was quite stylish." 
How should one understand this? It does't seem funny at all.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigsty

Comment: You are correct, it's not funny at all.

Comment: This is a poor pun, inducing groans and eye-rolling. Maybe not even that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pigs live in a [sty](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sty):

> a pen or enclosure for swine; pigpen.

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

The joke is using "sty*lish*" to mean "like a sty". It is a pun on the normal meaning of [stylish](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stylish):

> characterized by or conforming to style or the fashionable standard; fashionably elegant; smart or chic

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>